# Concatenate a pandas dataframe to CSV file without reading the entire file

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a quite large CSV file. I have a pandas dataframe that has exactly the columns with the CSV file.

I checked on stackoverflow and I see several answers suggested to `read_csv` then concatenate the read dataframe with the current one then write back to a CSV file.

But for a large file I think it is not the best way.

Can I concatenate a pandas dataframe to an existed CSV file without reading the whole file?

**Update:** Example

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFramce ({'a':1,'b':2}, index = [0])
df1.to_csv('my.csv')

df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'a':3, 'b':4}, index = [1])
# what to do here? I would like to concatenate df2 to my.csv
```

The expected `my.csv`

```
  a b
0 1 2
1 3 4
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Hi @StephenRauch so how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using [`mode='a'`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv):

MCVE:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame ({'a':1,'b':2}, index = [0])
df1.to_csv('my.csv')

df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'a':3, 'b':4}, index = [1])
df2.to_csv('my.csv', mode='a', header=False)

!type my.csv  #Windows machine use 'type' command or on unix use 'cat'
```

Output:

```
,a,b
0,1,2
1,3,4
```